# replace xml child element text with value from a list python

Tags: python, xml, list

I want to replace the text element of a child with a value held in a list.

```
<weighting name="weighting">
        <aWeight>false</aWeight>
        <cWeight>true</cWeight>
</weighting>
```

I am trying to change the text value for aWeight to true. I have tried to do it with this code.

```
elems = dom.findall('aWeight')
for elem in elems:
    if user_settings.new_settings[5] == 'true':
        '<aWeight>'.text = 'true'

dom.write('output.xml')
```

It's writing the file but the value is still staying at false. Does anyone have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code stands it's not accessing the `elem` variable to change the node value, you need to tell the operation "where" it needs to operate.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
elems = ET.fromstring('<weighting><aWeight>false</aWeight><cWeight>true</cWeight></weighting>')

test_condition = ['false', 'not set', 'bananas']

elems2 = elems.findall("aWeight")
for elem in elems2:
    print elem.text
    if elem.text in test_condition: 
        elem.text = 'true' 
    print elem.text
print ET.tostring(elems)
```

Comment: Hi, I changed it to:                                                                               `elems = dom.findall('aWeight')
for elem in elems:
    if elem == user_settings.new_settings[5]:
        '<aWeight>'.text = 'true'`, but it still won't work

Comment: Hi @MarkKelly, I've edited this so it's now a standalone fragment, which should work in the way that you are intending.

Comment: @ Graham Nicol Hi Graham, that does help a lot. But I need to compare the xml children with a value stored in a list. Any ideas on how I would do that?

Comment: One last edit to take the `false` into a test condition and see if the value matches one of the three values in that `List`

Comment: Thank you, I'm sure that this will help me figure things out

Comment: Please upvote the answer (click the up-arrow) if you found it useful, and accept it as an answer if it helped solve the issue. Happy to help.